# i have $route['administrator/(:any)'] = "$1"; where i want to bypass administrator and load method and function in codeigniter 3.0.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have
`$route['administrator/(:any)'] = "$1";`

> where i want to bypass administrator and load method and function in `codeigniter 3.0.4` but get 404 page not found actually what i want to do is i have a member class with login function and i what want to show login just like `administrator/member/login` url can any one help me to route in such way as well as any other class respectively `administrator/method/function`

Comment: so what is your expected URL and which action you want to run...? and what is your controller and methods. update your code.

Comment: @Yash actually administrator is just param to show administrator and i expectation is when i run administrator/member/login in url bar the controller member and its function login should be load respectively when i load administrator/any method/any function it should route to method and function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this URL:

```
administrator/member/login
```

Than you can define as:

```
$route['administrator/member/login'] = "yourClassName/yourFunctionName";
```

If you have any additional param, than you can use it as slug:

```
$route['administrator/member/login/(:any)'] = "yourClassName/yourFunctionName/$1";
```

Note that, if `administrator` is your project name than remove it from route as:

```
$route['member/login'] = "yourClassName/yourFunctionName";
```

**[CI URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)**

Comment: here administrator is just prama i give to look admin login as you mention if i do that it just work for specific class and function which do not routes dynamically to other class and function for example if i want to load administrator/page/list @devpro

Comment: @VijayThulungRai: no it will not hurt others. but if you use like that: `$route['(:any)/(:any)']` it will hurt others

Comment: if i do as u mention i have to route each contorller which i want load through administrator param actually in my older version of CI i route in same way i mention and when i run administrator/member/login and it load  class member / function login and what ever class i run along with administrator but now in CI 3.0.4 the same route and action not working

Comment: u need to defined routes , can u show me your urls, and class name+function name @VijayThulungRai

Comment: i want to mail you my file can you give me your account

Comment: @VijayThulungRai I can't give u .. For solution u can chk my profile